# Exercise about retract of $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ homeomorphic to $S^1$

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology

I have been working through the following exercise:

> Consider $X = GL (n, \mathbb{C})$ with respect to the Euclidean topology in $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$.
>
> Find a subspace $Y \subset X$ such that $Y$ is homemorphic to $S^1$ and $Y$ is a retract of $X$.
>
> Show that the fundamental group $\pi_1 (X, x)$ is infinite for all $x \in Y$.

Let's consider the set $Y$ which consists of all matrices
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
z & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation*}
with $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z| = 1$.

Then $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ and it is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Let $r : X \rightarrow Y$ be the map defined by
\begin{equation*}
r(A) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\det A}{|\det A|} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
for all matrices $A \in X$. This map is continuous because the determinant is a continuous map and every matrix in $X$ has non-zero determinant. Besides, $r$ is a retraction of $X$ to $Y$, because $r|_Y$ is the identity map on $Y$.

Let's consider the inclusion $i : Y \rightarrow X$ and a point $x \in Y$. Since $r$ is a retraction, the group homomorphism
\begin{equation*}
i_* : \pi_1 (Y, x) \rightarrow \pi_1(X, x)
\end{equation*}
is injective. Then $\pi_1(X, x)$ is infinite, because $\pi_1 (Y, x)$ is an infinite (cyclic) group.

Is this solution acceptable?

Comment: This looks fine. For extra credit, can you show $GL(n,\Bbb C)$ deformation retracts to $U(n)$? :P

Comment: @TedShifrin I'll think about it :)